# coldfusion imap An exception occurred when setting up mail server parameters

Tags: email, coldfusion, imap

I am trying to access my Microsoft Exchange server with Coldfusion cfimap so I can move mail out of the junk mail folder. I am using CF10. I want to just test getting the folder list.

```
<cfscript>
  variables.popAttributes = {
    server = ...,
    port = 995,
    username = ...,
    password = ...
  };
</cfscript>
<cfimap action="open"
  connection="variables.folders"
  secure="yes"
  server="#variables.popAttributes.server#"
  port="#variables.popAttributes.port#"
  username="#variables.popAttributes.username#"
  password="#variables.popAttributes.password#" />
<cfimap action="listallfolders" 
  connection="variables.folders"
  name="variables.folderQry" />
<cfdump var="#variables.folderQry#" />
<cfimap action="close"
  connection="variables.folders" />
```

When I try to run the above code, I get an exception from the "open" tag.

> **An exception occurred when setting up mail server parameters.**
>
> This exception was caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: +OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.; nested exception is: com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: +OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready..

I'd think that the message saying OK the service is ready should mean that it would move on to the next cfimap tag.

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting IMAP operations on a POP3 connection.  POP3 has no concept of folders.

Try port 993.